# error get function data insert from postgree to c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, pgadmin

My Code on C# (Visual Studio

```
private void button_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            sql = @"select * from st_insert(:_name,:_phone_number,:_address,:_height,:_weight,:_age)";
            cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_name", textBox_name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_phone_number", textBox_phone_number.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_address", textBox_address.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_height", textBox_height.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_weight", textBox_weight.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_age", textBox_age.Text);
            if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
            {
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Success insert a new Customers", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                button_load.PerformClick();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Insert Fail", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

function insert on pgadmin

```
create function st_insert ( _name character, _phone_number character,   
                           _address character, _height character,   
                           _weight character, _age integer )
returns int 
as $$ 
    begin 
        insert into customers ( name, phone_number, address, height, weight, age )
        values ( _name, _phone_number, _address, _height, _weight, _age );

        if found 
            then return 1; 
        else 
            return 0; 
        end if; 
    end $$ language plpgsql
```

Show error when i click button_insert :

error 42883 function st_insert(text,text,text,text,text,text) does not exist

Comment: Are you sure your ConnectionString connects to the correct database?

Answer (score 0):

The last argument of the function is `_age integer` but you add the parameter as a `text`.
The error message confirms this, saying it does not find a function whose last argument is a text.

--> change the parameter type to an integer